# how does FPS affect on video processing

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-processing

I am new to video processing. I am using Opencv and python to process videos and save them. 
for saving a video I used this line of code:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter(name,fourcc, 20,(320,180),False)
```

this code gives me a 20 fps output, My question how fps parameter affects on video processing and what is important to know about it?
Is it about the size of output or what?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File size is indeed affected by the frame rate. The higher the frame rate the more images that are packed into each second of video, so the file size goes up. More images is more data which also means higher processing times as well.

The standard fps used for tv is 30 or 29.97 fps. Cinematic standards are 24 or 23.97 fps. If I were recording a video game I would want to keep that at least in the 30 fps range but 60 would be better. Depending on the source though.

This is tough to answer because the answer really depends on the video source. You should try and stay true to that if you can to maintain the same quality and user experience of the original. Doing 24 or 30 if you are not sure what the source is should be fine.

Reducing the frame rate for your videos from whatever they defaulted to can affect them greatly. Anything from how smooth the video plays to the style you are going for.